# Есть ли в C# RAII обёртка для мьютекса, которая бы при захвате блокировала его?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mutex, raii

Есть ли в C# RAII обёртка для мьютекса, которая бы при захвате блокировала его по аналогии `std::lock_guard` из С++? Например что бы можно было написать что-то подобное:

```
int Foo() {
    std::lock_guard <std::mutex> lock (some_mutex) ;
    ...
    return a;
    ...
    return b;
    ...
    return c;
}
```

Comment: возможно WaitOne() в конструкторе объекта-декоратора для мьютекса?

Comment: @МихаилКошкарёв ну вопрос в этом и заключается, есть ли специализированные классы для этого. Если есть то какие, если нет, то есть ли универсальные RAII обёртки в C# впринципе.

Comment: RAII обёртки в C# это реализаторы IDisposable и using(), обертки для мьютекса - не думаю.

Comment: @МихаилКошкарёв спасибо. А есть какие-то стандартные, общепринятые реализации этого интерфейса, которые принимали бы в качестве аргумента пользовательский удалитель (т.е. функцию или лямбду которая будет выполнять при высвобождении ресурса).

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Я плюсы не знаю, мне вопрос непонятен. Блокировки в C# есть разные и для разных целей. Простой вариант - `lock (someObject) { ... }`

Comment: @Monk У меня есть несколько критических секций в коде в которых нужно защитить несколько объектов и переменных. Я в С++ использую для этого мьютекс который управляется через RAII (т.е. всё его высвобождения происходят автоматически). Автоматические высвобождения тут нужны что бы защититься от дедлока когда в критической секции вылетает ексепшн. Если быть до конца честным, то после дясятка дедлоков в одном сервеном проекте, я, со своей внимательностью, вообще запретил себе лочить мьютексы как-то еще кроме RAII.

Comment: @mrFieldy обычный lock (object) освобождает блокировку при исключениях. И любой using сделает то же самое. Если у вас всё в рамках одного процесса, то вам даже не нужны никакие внешние классы, можно делать просто lock на поле класса например, который снаружи будет просто безопасен.

Comment: @monk а ведь точно, необязательно отправлять в lock все ресурсы, которые надо синхронизировать, достаточно отправить один из них. Спасибо. Вы мне помогли решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на стандарт и общепринятость, но мне это видится как-то так:

```
public class NamedMutex : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Mutex namedMutex;
    private readonly bool createdNew;
    private Action disposeAction;

    public NamedMutex(string name, Action action)
    {
        namedMutex = new Mutex(false, name, out createdNew);
        disposeAction = action;
        namedMutex.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposeAction.Invoke();
        namedMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        namedMutex.Dispose();
    }
}
```

upd. при использовании с await следует учитывать поток, в котором мьютекс будет высвобождён.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Писать свои RAII обёртки я умею. Ваш вариант будет работать только с именованными мьютексами что является серьёзной проблемой. В RAII объектах которые захватывают и освобождают мьютексы принято передавать эти самые мьютексы в конструктор, а не создавать их внутри (вам ведь этот мьютекс нужно использовать в других критических секциях тоже). Вопрос был задан именно с той целью что-бы не писать свою обёртку каждый раз. .NET богаче std на всякие такие штуки, неужели там что-то нереализованно что есть в std?